# How do I configure git to automatically configure local branches to track for pulling?

Tags: git

Say I have a local branch `master` and a remote branch `remote/branch_one`. Is there a way to give a single command to checkout a local branch that automatically tracks the remote branch without explicitly indicating the remote branch? I'm thinking of a command like this:

`git checkout -t -b branch_one`

Right now, I've tried:

```
git checkout -b branch_one
git checkout -tb branch_one
```

I'd like to avoid explicitly having to say:

```
git branch --set-upstream branch_one origin/branch_one
```

I feel like git should be smart enough to, given a flag, connect my local branch to my remote branch without having to specify the remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

```
git push -u origin <branchname>
```

`push` pushes your branch up to the remote repository, and the `-u` tells it to also set your local up to track the remote

Comment: What if `<branchname>` already exists? I don't want to create a new branch on my remote; I want to create a local branch that tracks my remote branch.

Comment: have you tried `git branch -t` ? (Note: not used it myself, but the `--help` for that option sounds plausible)